# JMeter and TIBCO EMS

Tags: jmeter, tibco-ems

Is it possible to use Jmeter with TIBCO EMS? Because I am trying to connect to EMS servers through JMeter JMS plugin and not able to succeed on that.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Error Log

```
 WARN  - jmeter.protocol.jms.sampler.JMSSampler: Name not found: 'com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsQueueConnectionFactory' javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name not found: 'com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsQueueConnectionFactory'
    at com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsContext.lookup(TibjmsContext.java:713)
    at com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsContext.lookup(TibjmsContext.java:489)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.sampler.JMSSampler.threadStarted(JMSSampler.java:295)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread$ThreadListenerTraverser.addNode(JMeterThread.java:504)
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:984)
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:985)
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverse(HashTree.java:967)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.threadStarted(JMeterThread.java:479)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.initRun(JMeterThread.java:468)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:239)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What error do you get? Can you provide the trace?

Comment: Just a guess: 1) Is this the right server you are connecting to? <br> 2) Is it possible that you need to specify the prefix like "java:comp/env/com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsQueueConnectionFactory" <br> 3) Can you somehow see the JNDI tree on the server that your connecting to and see if that object is really there?

Comment: @superfilin , 1) It is correct server only. 2) This i will check it , I guess it may not  be possible 3) I've checked the same with HermesJMS and its listed there.

Comment: Thank u all for the response.Successfully tweaked the source code of jmeter and working like charm :)

Answer (score 1):

We did come across this problem in the past but worked around using BSF Sampler and scripted using tib library in groovy.

Answer (score 1):

- copy the jars from TIBCO_HOME\ems\version\lib to jmeter\lib
- Initial Context Factory: com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory
- restart jmeter

Answer (score 0):

Well that sounds like your `ConnectionFactory` (via JNDI) could not be found on the EMS Server side. Check within TIBCO EMS what the configured connection factory names are ;)

Usually `QueueConnectionFactory` should be there as default name.

Answer (score -1):

> **Follow below steps, it will work**
>
> Initial connection Factory :
>   com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory
>
> Provider URL :   tcp://hostname:7222
>
> ConnectionFactory : QueueConnectionFactory or(TopicConnectionFactory)
>
> Destination : sample
>
> username : raghu
>
> password : raghu